# Formatting code in PhpStorm does not work as I need it to work

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, code-formatting

How to use automatic line wrap and code formatting together in PhpStorm? My PhpStorm version is 2019.3.1

My SQL statements and my Strings look like the pic below.

What do I have to do, that the automatic wrapped lines do NOT jump to **column 1** in the editor?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> What do I have to do, that the automatic wrapped lines do NOT jump to column 1 in the editor?

Configure it accordingly (affects soft wrapped lines only, obviously): `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Soft Wraps | Use original line's indent for wrapped parts`

[image]

Comment: WoW! It works like a charm, thank you very much!
Do you have such a solution also for sql-Statements in php-Variables? These also are taking place on the left also as my "Lore ipsum"-String.

Comment: @Cap How does it look? Please provide some code sample (so I can copy-paste it) and screenshot of how it looks on your setup.

Comment: @Cap it works in my test code -- it's aligned to the first/previous line indent. P.S. Since PHP 7.3 you can use indented HEREDOC/NOWDOC -- https://eidson.info/post/php-flexible-heredoc-nowdoc-syntax